# Preventing a search field from submitting when empty using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a search box where I'm already using jQuery to submit the form, I just don't know how to keep it from submitting if the search box text field is empty. Any help?

Here's my code:

`<a href="javascript:$('#searchPost').submit()">Search</a>`

Comment: why are binding jquery inline?

Comment: Agreed; the logic code shouldn't mix with content and presentation.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#searchPost').submit(function(event) {

   if ($(this).find('input').val() == '') {
      event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('searchPost').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    if (!document.getElementById('searchBoxID').value)
        e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a  tag within the head:

```
function submitSearch() 
{
  if (document.FormName.SearchTextBoxName.value) $('#searchPost').submit();
}
```

Update the link:

```
<a href="javascript:submitSearch()">Search</a>
```

Comment: You could remove the `!= ""` if you want; empty strings evaluate to `false` and non-empty strings evaluate to `true` in JavaScript.